# How to fix CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

Good afternoon,

I had this error `The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception.` and this `Incorrect syntax near 'CrystalDecisions'` when i run the program on server.

I tried a lot of things to solve this.

Things i tried:

1. Verify dll's
2. On build insert dll with exe files
3. Re-install SAP Bussiness Enterprise 4.0
4. Re-install CrystalReport both
   versions(x32,x64) and unistall one to use just one(with that i had
   more problems because my company software work with both versions)
5. Verify FrameWork i'm using because for this specific CrystalReport funciton i needed to change **Framework 4.0 Client Profile** to only **Framework 4.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution i find was on change TargetCPU on Project Properties -> Compile -> Advanced Compile Options -> Set Target CPU from **X86** to **AnyCPU**